# does nodejs settimeout share variable in different loops

Tags: javascript, node.js

While test the settimeout function of Nodejs, Put settimeout in two for loops ,**if both the for loops have the same variables name i**, It seems to be that the two settimeout functions are sharing the variable.

**code:**

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) { 
    var tm1=setTimeout(function(){
         console.log(i); 
            }, 0); 
}
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    (function (x) {
        var tm2=setTimeout(function () { console.log(x); }, 100);
    })(i);
}
```

Result: 6 6 6 1 2 3 4 5
**If the for loops have different variables name n and i**, the results look all right

**code:**

```
for (var n = 1; n <= 3; n++) { 
    //change the variable name from i to n
    setTimeout(function(){
         console.log(n); 
            }, 0); 
}
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    (function (x) {
        var tm2=setTimeout(function () { console.log(x); }, 100);
    })(i);
}
```

Result: 4 4 4 1 2 3 4 5

How to understand this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only function scope and no block scope in ES5. Your observation has nothing to do with the `setTimeout` function but with the javascript variable scope

[read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)